# How to specify directory for apt-get to save the packages

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu, terminal, apt-get

is there any way to specify the destination directory `for each download` in apt -get command to save all the downloaded packages in a custom directory instead of archive directory for offline use.

If yes then how to use this custom directory to reinstall application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `apt-get` manpage:

```
   /var/cache/apt/archives/
       Storage area for retrieved package files. Configuration Item:
       Dir::Cache::Archives.
```

You can specify it like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get -o Dir::Cache::Archives=/tmp install wget
```

Note that this will fail unless that directory has a *partial* sub-directory